# Rails - Polymorphic association join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am currently trying to set up a model structure that seems quite simple, but I haven't quite got it down.

I have a model `payment` that can belong to either a `customer` or a `supplier` (which can both have many `payments`).

My question is simply whether I need to manually create an interface table to allow this, or if declaring the polymorphic associations will do this for me?

e.g. I have:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :payment_originator, :polymorphic => true
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :payments, :as => :payment_originator
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :payments, :as => :payment_originator
end
```

Is this enough, or do I also need to use a generator to manually create the payment_originator model?

Thanks!

Comment: Your class names should be capitalized. You should be able to do `Customer.payments << Payment.new(...)` or `Supplier.payments << Payment.new(...)` without trouble without the `PaymentOriginator` model actually existing.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited them - was typing directly as an example instead of copying them from the app and missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the models go, this is good enough. You just need to migrate a `:payment_originator_type` and `:payment_originator_id` to the payments table. The associations you defined above will automatically fill these in for you.

Comment: Thanks for this - so I have it clear in my head, if I did a direct SQL query on the payments table, I would see something like "customer" in the :payment_originator_type column for payments from customers? Just want to be clear what this column is for so I remember how it works in future.

Comment: Yep, the _type column stores a string representing the class name. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations.